# Doctrine Command 'doctrine:mapping:import' is not defined in Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm encountering an issue with Doctrine in my Symfony project. When I try to run the command `doctrine:mapping:import` (`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity`), I get an error saying that the `command is not defined`. However, I can see other Doctrine commands listed when I run `php bin/console list doctrine`.

Here are the steps I've taken:

Created a Symfony project using **Symfony 5.4**.
Installed Doctrine using Composer (composer requires doctrine/annotations).
Checked the list of available Doctrine commands using php bin/console list doctrine, and doctrine:mapping:import is not listed.
I've checked the documentation, and it seems like doctrine:mapping:import should be a valid command.

What could be causing this issue? Is there something else I need to install or configure to make this command available?

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See [Official notice from Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).
This command is **deprecated** and you have to use `make:entity`.

Answer (score 0):

Play with composer.json and change these like;

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.10",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
"doctrine/orm": "2.15",
```

After changing the composer please `composer update`

And run `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity`

And then `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App\Entity`